# Can't get the text next to the radio button via JQuery

Tags: jquery, html, radio-button

I have the following Jquery code:

```
      $("button#submit").click(function () {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: "process.php",
                    data: { 'value1': lastRefId,
                        'value2': selectedStatusID
                    },
                    success: function (msg) {
                    //Get the text next to the radio button
                      var selectedText = $('input:radio:checked').next().html()
                        alert(selectedText); 
                        $("button.btn.btn-default,button.btn.btn-primary").removeClass("disabled");

                    },
                    error: function () {
                        //code 
                    }
                });
```

With the following HTML code:

```
<form id="pick-status-form">
   <div class='radio'><label><input type='radio' name='statusesList' value='1' class='statuses-list'>1</label></div>
   <div class='radio'><label><input type='radio' name='statusesList' value='2' class='statuses-list'>2</label></div>
   <div class='radio'><label><input type='radio' name='statusesList' value='3' class='statuses-list'>3</label></div>
   <div class='radio'><label><input type='radio' name='statusesList' value='4' class='statuses-list'>4</label></div>
```

I want to get the text after the radio button (just befor the closing label tag).
I tried the code:

```
   var selectedText = $('input:radio:checked').next().html()
   alert(selectedText);
```

But I get undefined every time.

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`html()` does not account for text nodes. You can try getting [`text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) of parent instead:

```
var selectedText = $('input:radio:checked').parent('label').text();
alert(selectedText);
```

You might want to trim the text down using `$.trim()` too.

Comment: You right, it works. But somehow it doesn't work when I put it after the  AJAX sucess...

Comment: That's another question.

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you try `$('input:radio:checked').val()` , as the text next to radio is the same as the value.